# Xcode resizes different elements in storyboard after every commit

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xib, xcode8

After every `git commit` when I open unchanged `storyboard` file, `Xcode` every time modifies sizes of few elements so I got warnings. So every time I need to make size changes to revert everything back. Is there a solution to fix this annoying bug? I got this behaviour both in `Xcode 8` and `Xcode 7`.

Comment: Do you use autolayout? You can just click "Update frames" and everything will be put back in place.

Comment: @almas yes I do use autolayout. No, after "Update frames" is clicked nothing is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Close your story board before commit.